# SDL Experience Optimization 8 with DXA 1.4 Installation Error

Tags: web8, dxa, sdl-tridion, experience-optimization

I am trying to install module “SDL DXA ExperienceOptimization Module 1.7”  (Downloaded from SDL Community site) On top of existing SDL web 8 CMS. I am getting below error.

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: Which version of DXA are you using? 1.4 or 1.7? Or are you trying to combine DXA 1.7 XO Module with DXA 1.4 Framework.  Note that such version combinations are not tested and not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

According to the error message, you don't have Experience Optimization TBBs in your CMS.

You must ensure that the Experience Optimization feature is installed on your CMS before running the DXA XO Module's `cms-import.ps1`.

If the Experience Optimization feature is installed, it should create XO TBBs in `/Building Blocks/Default Templates/Experience Optimization` for newly created Publications.

If you installed the XO feature after the DXA BluePrint was created, you have to use the SDL Template Builder to Create/update the Default Templates in the DXA BluePrint root Publication.

Comment: Hi Rick,  I am Unable to find correct version of SDL Optimization module with  DXA 1.4, Can you guide to me a link from where I can download the Correct Version.

Comment: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases?after=DXA_1.5_Release

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the Update, It seems that this Link have DXA 1.4  .Net Version only,  I am Looking for DXA 1.4 Java version for the same. Can you please help  on this.

Comment: These DXA Module Distributions are for .NET and Java. Indeed, they also contain .NET web application artifacts (and installer). For Java, the artifacts (for all versions) are in Maven Central.